# Android package by feature. How to prevent activity-driven packages from knowing about each other?

Tags: java, android, oop

I am now reading the Packages part of Agile Software Development - Principles, Patterns, Practices.

It is a good idea to package by feature.
It is a good idea to package by coherency, reusability and encapsulation.

So I have a MainActivity, which is something like a home screen
I have 5 more features all of which are represented by 5 more activities.
Each feature is in its own package.
From the MainActivity, one can get to all other 5 features by selecting an option from the actionbar or the main navigation.

However, now MainActivity knows about the other 5 packages and its package is highly dependent.

I came up with the idea to create a separate package, an Activity Selector, whose purpose is to know about all packages who contain activities.
And whenever MainActivity needs to call some feature, it should only depend on Activity Selector to call it and tell it what it needs. Then Activity Selector picks it up from there and calls the appropriate feature-activity-package.

This way none of the activities and their respective packages know about each other. Encapsulation is high, reusability is high, independence is high.

Leave out overengineering (I am doing this mainly to practice, not because my project actually needs it), I am concerned about two things:

*a. I've never seen anyone do something like that*

*b. How do I implement it, if it turns out to be a good idea?*

**1. Implementation idea 1: Activity Factory:**
- The factory accepts a Context in its constructor. I use a list of strings, and if Activity A wants to start Activity B, I pass the factory a name that corresponds to Activity B and the factory starts it.

**2. Implementation idea 2: Activity Mediator:**
- the mediator takes in both activities, and lets one start the other with an intent. But how do I prevent both packages containing both activities from knowing about each other

**3. Using a dependency injection framework like Dagger:**
- is that going to solve this problem? It will take the fun out of implementing it myself, and I believe that I should be able to write a framework similar to a framework I am considering using it, before actually using it, otherwise I will not learn and gain skills I need.

**4. Activity factory using Marker Interfaces**
- I create marker interfaces for each feature, and let activities in each feature implement them. Then a call to a factory requires certain feature by its marker interface type, and the factory creates the needed activity